# completionHandler connot be executed in unit test of Xcode, ex. asynchronous api - reverseGeocodeLocation of CLGeocoder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, asynchronous, clgeocoder

I understand CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(...) will be executed in another thread, so that completionHandler will be executed in the main thread once it successfully gets the result from Apple server. The problem is I cannot see what happened in the completionHandler when I'm using in unit tests(when I build the framework), but it works fine in the Application. For simplify my question, I extract the asynchronous part from my codes in unit test as follows:

```
func testGeo() {
    var location = CLLocation(latitude: 45.0, longitude: 135.5)
    var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    println("------fetch----->")
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:{ (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("[ERROR]: \(error) in getPlacemarkFromLocation")
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            println("[SUCCESS] get the placemark!")
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        } else {
            println("[ERROR] get 0 placemarks in getPlacemarkFromLocation")
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    })
    println("------wait--- -->")
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}
```

When I do this unit test, it seems to not execute the completionHandler because nothing to print in the console. Every time I use asynchronous api, I cannot get the return value successfully in my unit test. I need to use unit test to make sure all the pipe of my framework works well. This gonna make me crazy... How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the test functions exit before the completion handler finishes.

From Xcode 6, Apple shipped an asynchronous testing facility called **XCTestExpectation**. This thing enables us to wait some time before going out of scope. Usage is as simple as:

```
    let expect = self.expectationWithDescription("exp")
    sc.asyncCall(para) { (data, error) in

        XCTAssertNotNil(data)

        expect.fulfill()
    }

    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(1) { (error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            XCTAssert(false)
            NSLog("Timeout Error.")
            return
        }
    }
```